# Trello automation copy card but link original

Tags: automation, trello, trello-powerup, trelloapi, trellocard

I created a custom button using Trello's automations that enables me to copy a card from one board to another. However, when this action is performed, I want the new copied card to have a comment or attachment with the link to the original card.
Is this possible ? And if yes how ?

Thank you for your help !